Python list.remove() internals
How does python list.remove() work internally?
For example, when adding to Java sets, Java compares both hash() and equals() methods. Does python compare the __eq__() method or something else?
Alternatively, does the implementation vary? If so, what is the implementation for CPython, or Anaconda Python (presumably CPython)?

it goes through the iterable, check for value,  remove if the first occurence if found other wise give value error

It compares using __eq__ not __hash__. Try a=[1, 2, True]; a.remove(True) to see.

@KlausD. Is there a documentation for this? So, it only checks __eq__(), not __cmp__(), and nothing else? For example, this answer says that __eq__() does default to __cmp__() in some circumstances.

Well, it checks __eq__, independently of how it is implemented, if the implementation calls __cmp__, then it is like that.

From the documentation of the remove() method of all mutable sequence types:

s.remove(x) remove the first item from s where s[i] is equal to x

In general, "is equal to" means that the == operator returns True, and this calls the __eq__() dunder method.
Comparing with a Set type is inappropriate, because these are typically implemented using hash tables, so __hash__() is used first to find the hash bucket. Within a hash bucket, __eq__() is used to resolve collisions.
